# DOCTRINE 2 Use two entities for one object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am trying to update my database with this cli : php app/console doctrine:schema:update
But I have a conflict "The table with name '...' already exists" because i Have two entities (one for the front and one for the back) and the both are linked to one table. I would like to keep the both because it's not the same logical for the front and the back. Has anyone had the same problem or may explain me how i can fix my problem.

Comment: Why do you not want to use one entity for both cases? You can serialise it with only fields you need.

Comment: you can't have a database with tables with the same name, look at your Entity /* @ORM\Table(name="ANOTHER_NAME") */ _doctrine generate a name based on the class name if leaved blank_, or Just use deserializer as the first comment suggest ( take a look here: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem is to use one entity for both cases. But in every case when you don't need some fields just exclude it from serialised object.

If you have different fields in these entities and different purpose for them you can use [single table inheritance pattern](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) that needs some attribute (discriminator) that will decide which entity will be populated by data from DB.